# 3 Monitors 2 different graphic cards

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, nvidia-geforce

I am looking to add a third monitor to my workstation. I currently have 2 monitors connected to a geforce gt 120. I am wanting to find the cheapest solution on adding another monitor, I have a old ati x300 laying around and wanting to know if I would be able to use  that to power the other monitor and if it would conflict with my other graphic card (I am not a gamer). What I want to do is have the at x300 power 1 monitor via DVI and the gt 120 power 2 monitors via VGA and DVI.

edit: I'm running Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

If you have another x4 or x8 or x16 PCI-E - just try to put X300 it.

If you have only x1 PCI-E - use this method (use translator to read the article): http://habrahabr.ru/post/105406/ (1.6)